# The macros I previously defined no longer seems to work (Tex Studio)

Tags: macros

[image]I am using Tex Live and Tex studio.

The macros I defined months ago and which were working just fine until this morning seem no longer be working.

The macros appear in a pink box and the document doesn't compile at all. The macro is not reconnized.

As it was working find yeasterday, I supposed it's not an error in the code. 
So I tried o download the Tex Studio last version but the problem was still there.

Would someone have an idea of what is going on and could tell me what I should be doing for solving this (probably basic) issue?

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{xcolor}                              
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-trad1, ibidtracker=context]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\mkibid}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\addbibresource{thesegain2017.bib}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[acronym, translate=babel]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{acro}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\newcommand\rose[1]{\textcolor{magenta}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\rose{bob} et\gls{aiea}


\end{document}
```

Neither macros, nor acronyms are working

Thanks a lot

Comment: We would have to look at your macros to find out. Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you clarify if you talk about tex macros or texstudio macros? Maybe include a screenshot of this pink box.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot clarify because I don't know the difference :/

Comment: @mailysmanu, TeXstudio macros you define in the Menu, not in the `tex` files.

Comment: I am very sorry but I am a social science researcher with very few knowledge in LaTeX. Would it be possible for you to be a little more specific because I do not understand the meaning of your comment. I am very sorry about it.

Comment: By "menu" are you refering to "preamble". Are suggesting that I should open a new document .tex to define my macro?

Comment: @mailysmanu, no. You said that you don't know the difference between TeX macro and TeXstudio ones. TeX macros you define on preamble and does not depend of which editor you use. TeXstudio macros are macros for the editor TeXstudio, and you define in the Macro Menu. I believe that this is not your case. So your editor is not relevant to your problem. I guess that you pure LaTeX problem, that is, only codes to use in `tex` file.

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows in the log messages: *acro.tex not found*. So to use `\loadglsentries{acro}` you should have some tex file, I think.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification (yes it seems to be tex macro then). I do have a tex file for Acro and it is in the same folder than the one of my core texte. Also it was perfectly working yeasterday and I didn't do any change on that since then. so I really don't understand where the probleme come from..

Comment: @mailysmanu Is it possible that you've accidentally moved `acro.tex` to a different location or accidentally renamed it? (Open it in TeXstudio and read the full path name shown in TeXstudio's title bar and compare it with the path name of your main document file.)

Comment: Both of you were right, it comes from the code and I made a mistake in the path. Thanks a lot for your help !